# Disable ARC for part of the code in a single file

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks

I am running a subroutine which will have some implications on the memory occupied in the given time frame and has the capability to crash the app.

I am wondering if there is a macro that can force the app to disable ARC just for that particular block of code in a single file (similar to how you would implement native assembly instructions in a block of code).

Comment: Are you 100 % positive that you can’t do without the magic?

Comment: You can [disable ARC for individual files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project). Personally, I'd move your "subroutine" into a standalone class, separate it into its own file(s) and manage it that way, but it's hard to comment in too much detail without knowing the code.

Comment: Its nearly impossible!! The only way I can suggest is to move that particular block in to separate file and disable ARC in that file !!!

Comment: @MattGibson, DILi, thanks for the input. That's something I can do but that's making the code a bit ugly and out-of-place but I can work around it (maybe for now). Thanks!